# SUMIFS unable to properly parse data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

### The Problem:

For a cost tracking sheet that I'm creating an updated version of, I have a few different things for pulling the data from:

- A table representing employees and their different employee groups (which I then assigned each column as a named range for ease of use).
- A table representing different groups of task codes.
- A series of tables containing invoices from employees, their names, and the task code that invoice was charged to for different projects. I have assigned these columns to named ranges for ease of use, and to help differentiate the projects they come from.

The current formula I'm using (that is not working) is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(WP2C_Employee_Invoice,WP2C_Employee_Name,Project_Managers,WP2C_Employee_Task,Tasks[WP2C Implementation]))
```

Breaking down this formula to help you (and myself) understand where I may be going wrong:

`SUMPRODUCT(` is being used to sum up the values of the array that `SUMIFS` returns, since we're comparing ranges.

`SUMIFS(`:

- `WP2C_Employee_Invoice`, `WP2C_Employee_Name`, and `WP2C_Employee_Task` make up the table containing the invoices for each project, the employee they originate from, and the task code they fall under.
- `Project_Managers` is one of the groups of employees.
- `Tasks[WP2C Implementation]` is one of the groups of task codes.

The formula should (as far as I can tell) be comparing each line of the project invoice table and seeing if the employee and task are valid, producing an array of valid sums, which is then summed up by `SUMPRODUCT`.

However, the numbers produced are incorrect with a total of $125,598.41, as opposed to the correct sum of $845,380.11 (found using the table filters to get the values and then summing them). Using a `COUNTIFS` to see what may be causing it (by stripping the invoiced amount column and reusing the criteria), resulted in only 14 hits, as opposed to the correct value of 78 hits (from filtering).

#### What is wrong with my current formula, and what should be changed in order to find the correct results?

**Notes:**

Here is the `COUNTIFS` formula I used:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(WP2C_Employee_Name,Project_Managers,WP2C_Employee_Task,Tasks[WP2C Implementation]))
```

- Using only one set of criteria produces the correct result for that set of criteria, only when using both sets does it not work.

  - Using a set of criteria for one of the criteria groups, and a single piece of criteria for the other produces correct results for that case.
  - Could the error be caused by the resultant array being too large, causing only a portion of it to be compared and returned?
- **Update**: I created a UDF in order to finish this sheet, but I'd still like to know what's wrong with my formula. It would be nice to not have to enable macros for the sheet to function.

---

#### Sample Data

```
**Tables of different employee groupings**

*Table: Employee*

Employees
---------
Adair Anfossi
Alaric Pallesen
Alfonse Newbery
Allie Cleaton
Anabel Agg
Anthony Gawke
Arnuad Gwinnel
Averil Tofpik
Brandyn Hatchell
Camella Feaster
Carlina Fosbraey
Catharina Howen
Catharine Chessum
Clive Astbury
Cobby Sydry
Conni Bentje
Correy Fiddyment
Cynthia Alwin
Edvard Porker
Emmi Simmonett
Ethe Village
Etti Crum
Eugine Price
Eveline Paxforde
Evelyn Duffil
Fay Ambrozewicz
Fayina Stubley
Gary Sager
Genvieve Jinda
Glendon Slott
Hendrick Twort
Hussein Wheeliker
Immanuel Earwicker
Inglis Glossop
Jessalin Larvor
Joelly Piller
Kaia Giannazzo
Karyn Guild
Kimball Mayzes
Kristoffer Courtese
Lamond Bromwich
Laure Barbour
Laurens Mordey
Lilllie Blanket
Lorin Mc Caghan
Madelle Kinleyside
Margette Cawthry
Marmaduke Flynn
Micah Farrier
Milli Oneal
Monique Hullyer
Ninon Suffe
Norry Waghorn
Petra Corby
Rudolfo Weitzel
Scotty Trench
Sheeree Earney
Sheffield Hazeup
Simeon Galfour
Tailor Gorwood
Tim Joscelyn
Torry Ouldcott

*Table: PM*

Project Managers
----------------
Winny Burnup
Rubia Rushbrooke
Margaretha O'Neal
Dietrich Royden
Berry Dilloway
Guntar Scurlock
Pippo Oriel
Myrah Gwilt
Blake Arthey
Thorvald Chance
Odetta Morden
Arlyne Cooling
Donnie Stilliard
Elden Lynnett
King Odo
Moll Duddan
Seth Bakster
Benjie Caldecot
Mame Batt
Garvey Kieff
Carolina Snook

*Table: BA*

Business Analysts
-----------------
Gran Shipperbottom
Ciro Pyser
Debora Paradin
North Betho
Pier Lingwood
Tracey Prest
Tris Freshwater
Wadsworth Whiteoak
Whitby Hagston
Zacharias Lucchi
Zoe McGaffey

*Table:Boss*

Boss People
-----------
Joana Goom
Cathrin Batts
Starlin De Bruyne
Dorry Giroldo
Fayina Siveter

**Table: Tasks**

Planning    Implementation  Steady State    ODC     Foo     Bar
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1.1.1       1.2.1           1.3.1           1.4.1   1.5.1   1.6.1
1.1.2       1.2.2           1.3.2           1.4.2   1.5.2   1.6.2
1.1.3       1.2.3           1.3.3           1.4.3   1.5.3   1.6.3
1.1.4       1.2.4           1.3.4           1.4.4   1.5.4   1.6.4
1.1.5       1.2.5           1.3.5           1.4.5   1.5.5   1.6.5
1.1.6       1.2.6           1.3.6           1.4.6   1.5.6   1.6.6
1.1.7       1.2.7           1.3.7           1.4.7   1.5.7   1.6.7
1.1.8       1.2.8           1.3.8           1.4.8   1.5.8   1.6.8
1.1.9       1.2.9           1.3.9           1.4.9   1.5.9   1.6.9
1.1.10      1.2.10          1.3.10          1.4.10  1.5.10  1.6.10
1.1.11      1.2.11          1.3.11          1.4.11  1.5.11  1.6.11
1.1.12      1.2.12          1.3.12          1.4.12  1.5.12  1.6.12
1.1.13      1.2.13          1.3.13          1.4.13  1.5.13  1.6.13
1.1.14      1.2.14          1.3.14          1.4.14  1.5.14  1.6.14
1.1.15      1.2.15          1.3.15          1.4.15  1.5.15  1.6.15

**Table: Invoice**

Task    Name    Amount
----------------------
1.2.1   Thorvald Chance 9715.09
1.5.13  Ethe Village    2821.45
1.5.14  Emmi Simmonett  3476.83
1.4.13  Margette Cawthry    9158.92
1.2.1   Alfonse Newbery 593.32
1.6.7   Starlin De Bruyne   2292.64
1.5.14  Zoe McGaffey    7467.57
1.1.10  Torry Ouldcott  9602.67
1.6.9   Fay Ambrozewicz 1470.18
1.6.15  Scotty Trench   3780.66
1.5.11  Guntar Scurlock 8447.79
1.4.1   Evelyn Duffil   9198.83
1.1.14  Laurens Mordey  9210.71
1.1.2   Sheeree Earney  7397.47
1.6.14  Petra Corby 988.95
1.4.7   Hussein Wheeliker   3560.99
1.4.12  Ninon Suffe 1021.21
1.5.7   Glendon Slott   2265.31
1.6.8   Starlin De Bruyne   9833.57
1.6.14  Monique Hullyer 8309.45
1.2.13  Zoe McGaffey    7388.95
1.2.8   Tracey Prest    101.06
1.2.11  Lamond Bromwich 9365.05
1.6.7   Norry Waghorn   3646.33
1.2.1   Zacharias Lucchi    893.9
1.2.13  Winny Burnup    8986.16
1.6.11  Alfonse Newbery 1076.08
1.1.5   Milli Oneal 7810.15
1.6.8   Margette Cawthry    7508.17
1.1.4   Myrah Gwilt 3441.48
1.4.11  Micah Farrier   2315.92
1.3.14  Ciro Pyser  4839.45
1.6.14  Zacharias Lucchi    5494.76
1.1.8   Donnie Stilliard    2294.66
1.6.15  Eveline Paxforde    7285.86
1.6.9   Catharine Chessum   8922.08
1.4.7   Immanuel Earwicker  56.61
1.4.14  Myrah Gwilt 9371.23
1.1.15  Moll Duddan 6420.13
1.3.11  Sheffield Hazeup    4658.03
1.2.4   Debora Paradin  4174.61
1.5.1   Allie Cleaton   9493.53
1.4.6   Seth Bakster    5691.97
1.4.3   Blake Arthey    7822.19
1.6.4   Karyn Guild 5372.19
1.6.12  Alfonse Newbery 6114.4
1.2.9   Adair Anfossi   2471.88
1.3.11  Norry Waghorn   8237.61
1.2.7   Monique Hullyer 1500.68
1.6.11  Fay Ambrozewicz 5016.03
1.3.1   Eveline Paxforde    2572.38
1.2.10  Fay Ambrozewicz 4630.55
1.4.9   Laurens Mordey  6014.23
1.4.3   Joelly Piller   4612.03
1.5.9   Eveline Paxforde    9821.72
1.6.12  Blake Arthey    1507.67
1.4.8   Kimball Mayzes  9911.98
1.4.7   Allie Cleaton   8517.33
1.4.1   Petra Corby 528.43
1.6.2   Rubia Rushbrooke    9218.27
1.3.2   Sheeree Earney  7326.35
1.1.1   Myrah Gwilt 8861.3
1.4.13  Starlin De Bruyne   5601.28
1.2.4   Cynthia Alwin   3188.79
1.1.6   Debora Paradin  5216.2
1.1.7   Carlina Fosbraey    1670.62
1.2.10  Moll Duddan 8047.08
1.3.5   Scotty Trench   4627.22
1.5.7   Joelly Piller   1758.95
1.3.13  Catharina Howen 8087.02
1.4.9   Zacharias Lucchi    7053.97
1.6.8   Eveline Paxforde    8141.1
1.2.5   Milli Oneal 946.9
1.6.12  Emmi Simmonett  5893.37
1.2.14  Lorin Mc Caghan 5540.46
1.5.2   Mame Batt   8655.61
1.5.4   Madelle Kinleyside  941.35
1.2.14  Petra Corby 2301.35
1.2.7   Etti Crum   6078.62
1.6.9   Hendrick Twort  9133.62
1.6.15  Lilllie Blanket 2982.95
1.2.5   King Odo    2669.14
1.5.15  Monique Hullyer 8275.02
1.5.10  Whitby Hagston  43.44
1.1.9   Joelly Piller   100.87
1.2.12  Glendon Slott   1837.59
1.5.4   Madelle Kinleyside  8885.87
1.5.9   Winny Burnup    2478.06
1.2.12  Joelly Piller   8459.54
1.3.2   Laurens Mordey  5265.88
1.4.10  Cobby Sydry 1626.93
1.5.15  Ninon Suffe 8167.83
1.5.7   Jessalin Larvor 8333.05
1.1.8   Edvard Porker   489.36
1.2.3   Joelly Piller   6535.34
1.1.8   Benjie Caldecot 7505.88
1.3.3   Sheffield Hazeup    9468.23
1.1.15  Berry Dilloway  2423.27
1.1.2   Laurens Mordey  775.65
1.1.14  Marmaduke Flynn 4818.48
1.6.7   Lorin Mc Caghan 622.55
1.4.8   Tailor Gorwood  9615.1
1.6.11  Edvard Porker   7321.09
1.4.5   Carlina Fosbraey    296.01
1.4.12  Donnie Stilliard    1856.58
1.1.13  Genvieve Jinda  5048.43
1.4.3   Garvey Kieff    5384.99
1.2.12  Lamond Bromwich 1617.96
1.5.15  Arnuad Gwinnel  5372.95
1.2.8   Catharina Howen 1064.47
1.6.13  Alfonse Newbery 3534.02
1.3.8   Alaric Pallesen 1999.13
1.4.11  Myrah Gwilt 6250.49
1.6.12  Immanuel Earwicker  4776.71
1.1.11  Monique Hullyer 3332.67
1.4.1   Blake Arthey    8403.02
1.6.1   Tailor Gorwood  1231.76
1.1.9   Jessalin Larvor 4857.18
1.1.15  Conni Bentje    3907.89
1.1.4   Rudolfo Weitzel 1053.7
1.2.6   Cynthia Alwin   8136.77
1.6.9   North Betho 9827.66
1.6.11  Ninon Suffe 7949.23
1.3.12  Joana Goom  275.46
1.3.14  Eugine Price    5099.63
1.6.12  Cathrin Batts   9994.42
1.3.2   Emmi Simmonett  2645.34
1.2.3   Carlina Fosbraey    2791.14
1.5.13  Simeon Galfour  1338.63
1.5.15  Seth Bakster    4275.21
1.1.1   Guntar Scurlock 7721.32
1.4.12  Berry Dilloway  864.96
1.6.1   Sheffield Hazeup    380.4
1.3.15  Wadsworth Whiteoak  399.64
1.1.12  Margaretha O'Neal   5590.61
1.6.4   Whitby Hagston  5805.37
1.3.9   Brandyn Hatchell    7304.19
1.6.2   Laure Barbour   9958.97
1.6.2   Donnie Stilliard    6788.46
1.4.8   Margette Cawthry    6003.43
1.5.6   Cynthia Alwin   545.05
1.1.6   Petra Corby 7275.12
1.5.5   Kaia Giannazzo  9033.18
1.1.3   Sheffield Hazeup    5626.91
1.2.1   Tailor Gorwood  5448.45
1.5.10  Karyn Guild 242.1
1.1.15  Zoe McGaffey    383.31
1.6.9   Joana Goom  3586.93
1.6.15  Genvieve Jinda  8262.36
1.5.6   Anabel Agg  5389.19
1.3.3   Edvard Porker   7448.42
1.4.3   Gary Sager  2322.04
1.1.11  Tim Joscelyn    1403.12
1.2.7   Ethe Village    3709.87
1.2.2   Etti Crum   8946.94
1.2.9   Adair Anfossi   292.41
1.3.1   Lamond Bromwich 1332.36
1.2.6   Catharine Chessum   2765.36
1.6.1   Benjie Caldecot 9089.82
1.3.11  Catharina Howen 7560.44
1.1.14  Hussein Wheeliker   257.17
1.2.13  Karyn Guild 7316.22
1.6.15  Petra Corby 8435.07
1.4.6   Norry Waghorn   5404.69
1.3.10  Hendrick Twort  6498.52
1.1.10  Benjie Caldecot 8892.11
1.2.13  Marmaduke Flynn 9722.28
1.1.14  Immanuel Earwicker  2358.12
1.4.10  Alaric Pallesen 6323.2
1.2.4   Laure Barbour   471.09
1.1.14  Kaia Giannazzo  4105.49
1.4.2   Rubia Rushbrooke    4828.01
1.5.15  Genvieve Jinda  9836.59
1.5.9   Marmaduke Flynn 5430.94
1.1.9   Elden Lynnett   4515.26
1.3.15  King Odo    3126.68
1.2.12  Garvey Kieff    3078.84
1.2.6   Mame Batt   49.06
1.4.4   Brandyn Hatchell    7298.19
1.6.9   Mame Batt   2968.03
1.6.8   Carolina Snook  8407.82
1.1.2   Karyn Guild 4072.88
1.5.13  Gary Sager  100.71
1.1.3   Ethe Village    685.79
1.1.15  Brandyn Hatchell    8009.48
1.5.2   Starlin De Bruyne   3114.06
1.1.3   Monique Hullyer 25.79
1.5.4   Seth Bakster    1721.86
1.3.8   Evelyn Duffil   8081.07
1.3.13  Zoe McGaffey    9299.3
1.3.14  Averil Tofpik   8014.34
1.1.11  Starlin De Bruyne   2406.34
1.4.3   Tim Joscelyn    8212.04
1.6.8   Fayina Stubley  1546.14
1.6.2   Allie Cleaton   9190.08
1.4.15  Hussein Wheeliker   1441.17
1.2.2   Eveline Paxforde    1800.68
1.4.11  Arlyne Cooling  1942.26
1.3.10  Monique Hullyer 7318.68
1.1.6   Benjie Caldecot 1105.21
1.3.10  Adair Anfossi   2781.44
1.4.6   Gary Sager  2469.43
1.3.12  Donnie Stilliard    6358.63
1.1.10  Inglis Glossop  155.19
1.4.5   Glendon Slott   6374.52
1.3.15  Thorvald Chance 6065.07
1.5.11  Lamond Bromwich 8669.72
1.2.15  Catharine Chessum   5389.72
1.6.11  Adair Anfossi   1514.07
1.5.14  Alfonse Newbery 2159.27
1.3.11  Carolina Snook  8201.83
1.3.6   Camella Feaster 3595.27
1.6.12  Brandyn Hatchell    8885.69
1.5.12  Berry Dilloway  8280.73
1.1.6   Camella Feaster 5858.2
1.1.15  Tracey Prest    5711.57
1.5.1   Zacharias Lucchi    4995.7
1.6.6   Debora Paradin  275.9
1.3.3   Etti Crum   9334.22
1.4.7   Zacharias Lucchi    569.1
1.3.1   Donnie Stilliard    8073.06
1.1.12  Fayina Siveter  81.7
1.4.2   King Odo    5049.83
1.5.1   Eugine Price    448.63
1.3.5   Benjie Caldecot 835.84
1.3.8   Edvard Porker   4912.53
1.2.11  Margette Cawthry    3100.15
1.3.4   Zoe McGaffey    2106.87
1.2.2   Myrah Gwilt 7290.03
1.3.3   Adair Anfossi   4287.63
1.1.12  Wadsworth Whiteoak  9990.08
1.3.5   Winny Burnup    7596.13
1.1.12  Tim Joscelyn    9030.48
1.2.11  Alaric Pallesen 4737.78
1.4.3   Gary Sager  1774.03
1.3.3   Brandyn Hatchell    3478.51
1.6.4   Guntar Scurlock 2028.82
1.1.6   Kristoffer Courtese 6223.17
1.1.11  Averil Tofpik   4409.05
1.3.3   Micah Farrier   8433.24
1.4.9   Winny Burnup    9946.88
1.1.6   Sheffield Hazeup    31.13
1.2.5   Fayina Stubley  3961.84
1.1.12  Sheeree Earney  6958.95
1.2.7   Guntar Scurlock 3898.94
1.2.7   Ciro Pyser  1309.02
1.4.15  Correy Fiddyment    7311.58
1.5.5   Gran Shipperbottom  6047.14
1.1.13  Starlin De Bruyne   7020.13
1.4.11  Garvey Kieff    3030.9
1.6.3   Inglis Glossop  9283.64
1.1.13  Cathrin Batts   4307.47
1.1.2   Hendrick Twort  8995.56
1.1.14  Clive Astbury   4906.4
1.4.15  Dietrich Royden 4047.53
1.2.7   Debora Paradin  9893.65
1.1.2   Dorry Giroldo   588.07
1.1.7   Donnie Stilliard    1072.88
1.2.3   Torry Ouldcott  3360.1
1.1.8   Allie Cleaton   8298.47
1.3.1   Catharine Chessum   489.63
1.1.14  Joelly Piller   4332.69
1.6.9   Tailor Gorwood  5692.35
1.2.13  Tracey Prest    1074.81
1.2.2   Zoe McGaffey    6820.9
1.6.8   Hendrick Twort  2256.43
1.4.1   Arlyne Cooling  3916.87
1.3.4   Pier Lingwood   2125.21
1.2.5   Kristoffer Courtese 2492.43
1.1.6   Gary Sager  2582.35
1.2.12  Camella Feaster 7615.47
1.2.13  Lorin Mc Caghan 6445.51
1.1.10  Ciro Pyser  6235.12
1.3.6   Tracey Prest    4699.27
1.3.8   Catharine Chessum   3464.1
1.3.6   Etti Crum   8879.9
1.4.5   Micah Farrier   6238.49
1.2.12  Lamond Bromwich 2293.56
1.6.12  Carolina Snook  8097.49
1.2.7   Ethe Village    4354.58
1.6.1   Starlin De Bruyne   1173.53
1.1.13  Tracey Prest    7787.96
1.5.10  Ninon Suffe 2222
1.2.6   Conni Bentje    3611.83
1.2.11  Sheeree Earney  3819.04
1.1.6   Scotty Trench   1817.22
1.5.6   Arlyne Cooling  7645.7
1.1.8   Sheeree Earney  6901.53
1.1.2   Joana Goom  7615
1.2.9   Winny Burnup    235.99
1.2.12  North Betho 7387.64
1.3.12  King Odo    2762.05
1.5.10  Debora Paradin  8655.98
1.6.3   Genvieve Jinda  6677.9
1.2.9   Pippo Oriel 2548.46
1.3.5   Zoe McGaffey    9807.93
1.6.12  Seth Bakster    8612.98
1.5.10  Monique Hullyer 9265.56
1.5.7   Emmi Simmonett  316.68
1.5.2   Eveline Paxforde    7472.74
1.6.9   Ciro Pyser  2778.79
1.6.10  Scotty Trench   5429.6
1.2.8   Eveline Paxforde    4502.44
1.5.12  Winny Burnup    3658.46
1.2.2   Fayina Siveter  2533.42
1.4.9   Benjie Caldecot 1333.63
1.5.3   Fayina Stubley  2289.8
1.3.9   Emmi Simmonett  770.32
1.2.5   King Odo    6366.68
1.3.15  Carolina Snook  1906.97
1.6.3   Alfonse Newbery 7052.42
1.6.9   Torry Ouldcott  2829.58
1.1.5   Scotty Trench   4693.14
1.4.10  Kaia Giannazzo  2543.72
1.1.12  Eugine Price    1104.95
1.3.14  Gran Shipperbottom  6928.22
1.3.13  Tris Freshwater 4238.82
1.5.4   Lorin Mc Caghan 41.7
1.5.9   Fay Ambrozewicz 9201.43
1.4.10  Lilllie Blanket 3361.83
1.6.6   Cobby Sydry 9605.81
1.4.8   Catharine Chessum   1493.31
1.1.3   Alaric Pallesen 6306.47
1.5.7   Debora Paradin  1581.49
1.1.10  Edvard Porker   3576.21
1.4.13  Guntar Scurlock 9595.11
1.5.3   Blake Arthey    7891.87
1.2.3   Guntar Scurlock 6833.74
1.4.10  Moll Duddan 6178.02
1.5.12  Hussein Wheeliker   4157.7
1.4.10  Garvey Kieff    3421.3
1.2.11  Seth Bakster    5423.47
1.6.8   Fayina Siveter  8852.96
1.4.15  Cobby Sydry 4812.2
1.6.1   Genvieve Jinda  7332.62
1.1.5   Kaia Giannazzo  132.82
1.5.3   Laurens Mordey  5794.44
1.2.4   Simeon Galfour  114.07
1.5.3   Benjie Caldecot 3099.49
1.6.10  Correy Fiddyment    7291.74
1.6.1   Odetta Morden   7445.29
1.3.2   Averil Tofpik   8158.42
1.2.2   Zoe McGaffey    7314.84
1.3.13  Sheffield Hazeup    3434.89
1.4.11  Whitby Hagston  8313.37
1.2.11  Laurens Mordey  9751.11
1.3.2   Pier Lingwood   5783.73
1.4.5   Laurens Mordey  5655.37
1.2.15  Tracey Prest    3266.99
1.2.7   Margaretha O'Neal   7818.63
1.5.6   Fay Ambrozewicz 3511.31
1.1.15  Arnuad Gwinnel  705.05
1.5.1   Laure Barbour   3937.09
1.6.10  Laurens Mordey  951.27
1.4.13  Clive Astbury   3670.84
1.1.7   Fayina Stubley  7783.21
1.2.3   Immanuel Earwicker  9267.98
1.1.9   Gran Shipperbottom  8044.21
1.6.4   Edvard Porker   8012.81
1.5.11  Alaric Pallesen 7362.88
1.4.5   Laure Barbour   2897.63
1.6.2   Rudolfo Weitzel 977.48
1.6.11  Anabel Agg  6137.31
1.5.4   Odetta Morden   3657.7
1.1.12  Arnuad Gwinnel  8461.81
1.5.8   Camella Feaster 4290.39
1.4.7   Laure Barbour   2545.04
1.2.12  Fayina Siveter  4222.89
1.6.15  Torry Ouldcott  4882.78
1.3.1   Elden Lynnett   9028.55
1.4.14  Norry Waghorn   8062.17
1.6.15  Arlyne Cooling  4987.34
1.2.2   Correy Fiddyment    1200.02
1.2.6   Alaric Pallesen 236.78
1.3.14  Tracey Prest    3617.06
1.4.12  Etti Crum   8583.19
1.5.13  Sheffield Hazeup    3201.84
1.5.13  Wadsworth Whiteoak  623.16
1.2.11  Carolina Snook  4342.41
1.1.8   Whitby Hagston  6520.07
1.5.15  Eveline Paxforde    9292.52
1.2.10  Conni Bentje    2250.3
1.3.11  Cathrin Batts   2601.18
1.4.10  Debora Paradin  8687.61
1.6.3   Emmi Simmonett  7075.56
1.4.1   Tracey Prest    5674.76
1.5.3   Fay Ambrozewicz 5650.79
1.4.6   Arlyne Cooling  5620.68
1.2.4   Dorry Giroldo   3688.42
1.3.1   Averil Tofpik   6455.08
1.3.13  Blake Arthey    740.61
1.1.11  Arlyne Cooling  2471.2
1.2.10  Benjie Caldecot 9954.11
1.2.5   Mame Batt   980.78
1.1.7   Adair Anfossi   2246.21
1.1.15  Eugine Price    2687.5
1.1.6   Immanuel Earwicker  7912.1
1.4.12  Sheffield Hazeup    5399.99
1.3.11  Whitby Hagston  705.79
1.4.1   Kaia Giannazzo  9278.43
1.5.10  Anthony Gawke   3190.69
1.1.5   Alfonse Newbery 395.27
1.4.5   Immanuel Earwicker  5526.27
1.3.13  Simeon Galfour  2673.39
1.1.11  Carolina Snook  7995.13
1.2.15  Guntar Scurlock 9760.09
1.2.11  Karyn Guild 4140.45
1.1.2   Tris Freshwater 9054.31
1.4.12  Laure Barbour   6502.6
1.6.10  Alaric Pallesen 2311.84
1.5.7   Donnie Stilliard    5812.43
1.2.7   Glendon Slott   4048.15
1.3.12  Adair Anfossi   3689.25
1.5.7   Berry Dilloway  1644.27
1.1.14  Alfonse Newbery 7000.85
1.2.12  Karyn Guild 3761.86
1.3.12  Allie Cleaton   1490.07
1.3.5   Carolina Snook  6646.22
1.6.15  Fayina Stubley  6629.31
1.5.6   Immanuel Earwicker  7209.37
1.1.2   Allie Cleaton   289.36
1.4.3   Hendrick Twort  516.22
1.2.2   Blake Arthey    3972.8
1.2.12  Etti Crum   4183.22
1.2.15  Sheffield Hazeup    13.64
1.6.4   Zacharias Lucchi    6122.49
1.3.11  North Betho 9467.29
1.3.1   Zoe McGaffey    2503.95
1.1.11  Winny Burnup    8358.72
1.4.8   Alaric Pallesen 3821.17
1.5.6   Arlyne Cooling  3747.98
1.4.5   Catharine Chessum   7040.16
1.1.15  Rubia Rushbrooke    5159.72
1.2.4   Cobby Sydry 2120.61
1.1.13  Tracey Prest    4133.59
1.6.2   Norry Waghorn   6124.59
1.5.1   Fay Ambrozewicz 7156.19
1.5.2   Seth Bakster    9333.18
1.5.1   Jessalin Larvor 6265.76
1.2.9   Alfonse Newbery 2971.06
1.3.10  Karyn Guild 3221.19
1.4.1   Tailor Gorwood  1504.29
1.3.7   Cobby Sydry 4152.13
1.4.12  Kimball Mayzes  7188.14
1.2.8   Elden Lynnett   1757.1
1.2.2   Catharina Howen 9485.94
1.2.5   Whitby Hagston  967.05
1.3.5   Rubia Rushbrooke    1514.13
1.4.10  Garvey Kieff    6760.31
1.3.6   Margette Cawthry    5222.36
1.3.13  Conni Bentje    192.86
1.2.12  Margette Cawthry    733.48
1.2.2   Monique Hullyer 8330.26
1.2.12  Sheeree Earney  2264.05
1.5.14  Alaric Pallesen 5681.89
1.5.13  Rudolfo Weitzel 6414.69
1.6.9   Myrah Gwilt 1221.41
1.1.2   Conni Bentje    9046.16
1.5.8   Sheffield Hazeup    4159.31
1.5.14  Fayina Siveter  3043.88
1.2.10  Rudolfo Weitzel 3550.5
1.1.14  Milli Oneal 5524.87
1.5.2   Carlina Fosbraey    316.86
1.6.3   Margette Cawthry    5549.34
1.5.12  Simeon Galfour  5195.86
1.2.3   Fayina Siveter  3863.01
1.6.7   King Odo    2386.33
1.1.9   Rudolfo Weitzel 1288.34
1.2.15  Tracey Prest    534.67
1.5.10  Tim Joscelyn    7571.9
1.3.5   Marmaduke Flynn 2461.2
1.1.12  Emmi Simmonett  3702.4
1.3.12  Monique Hullyer 2954.93
1.6.15  Tailor Gorwood  3984.12
1.5.14  Scotty Trench   7691.71
1.5.4   Milli Oneal 8952.79
1.5.8   Blake Arthey    8163.12
1.2.6   Catharine Chessum   8395.35
1.1.13  Thorvald Chance 298.94
1.5.5   Genvieve Jinda  2466.92
1.4.2   Cynthia Alwin   9544.67
1.2.13  Milli Oneal 8672.62
1.4.8   North Betho 7180.51
1.2.10  Arnuad Gwinnel  6937.82
1.3.4   Starlin De Bruyne   3740.57
1.4.12  Karyn Guild 1906.07
1.3.1   Cynthia Alwin   4233.39
1.1.11  Hussein Wheeliker   8439.75
1.4.2   Thorvald Chance 9901.92
1.5.14  Genvieve Jinda  4527.04
1.4.15  Hussein Wheeliker   905.32
1.1.13  Alfonse Newbery 4474.51
1.4.10  Camella Feaster 4780.16
1.3.1   Ciro Pyser  6874.6
1.1.12  Zacharias Lucchi    1650.89
1.1.13  Immanuel Earwicker  3712.52
1.6.6   Lorin Mc Caghan 9908.61
1.5.6   Marmaduke Flynn 5360.08
1.2.9   Dietrich Royden 6547.94
1.3.12  Edvard Porker   9987.46
1.6.3   Gran Shipperbottom  6537.64
1.2.11  Hendrick Twort  1390.69
1.2.8   Allie Cleaton   1442.18
1.1.3   Margette Cawthry    5279.16
1.3.2   Clive Astbury   7158.74
1.5.14  Seth Bakster    417.05
1.6.7   Camella Feaster 5559.85
1.5.12  Scotty Trench   6997.46
1.3.1   Alaric Pallesen 9107.87
1.4.15  Gary Sager  1643.9
1.4.12  Zacharias Lucchi    7359.5
1.3.13  Pier Lingwood   5670.93
1.3.9   Anabel Agg  9892.49
1.3.7   Lilllie Blanket 3588.78
1.4.9   Ciro Pyser  2363.15
1.5.8   Arlyne Cooling  1783.86
1.5.4   Blake Arthey    4446.45
1.3.3   Rudolfo Weitzel 8301.23
1.2.13  Donnie Stilliard    3650.56
1.4.4   Karyn Guild 9283.65
1.2.14  Sheffield Hazeup    4088.97
1.3.15  Rudolfo Weitzel 2541.63
1.6.6   Emmi Simmonett  7984.57
1.3.8   Carolina Snook  6944.6
1.6.13  Pippo Oriel 9590.7
1.1.15  Ethe Village    8128.29
1.1.13  Genvieve Jinda  4262.01
1.6.7   Fayina Siveter  1089.81
1.4.4   Cathrin Batts   9763.43
1.1.10  Myrah Gwilt 6965.77
1.6.13  Pier Lingwood   7759.36
1.4.10  Glendon Slott   6600.15
1.6.11  Alaric Pallesen 6705.81
1.2.7   Catharina Howen 9135.31
1.3.9   Odetta Morden   5908.85
1.5.9   Pier Lingwood   821.5
1.4.5   Karyn Guild 4655.84
1.3.3   Edvard Porker   6157.22
1.5.2   Wadsworth Whiteoak  6591.17
1.1.2   Zacharias Lucchi    6633.4
1.5.1   Conni Bentje    6621.78
1.3.8   Evelyn Duffil   2872.6
1.4.15  Eugine Price    2669.45
1.4.10  Elden Lynnett   2470.83
1.3.5   Clive Astbury   7669.11
1.2.11  North Betho 7321.61
1.2.5   Hussein Wheeliker   832.08
1.5.2   Catharine Chessum   518.5
1.6.5   Mame Batt   636.04
1.4.2   Kimball Mayzes  8624.09
1.1.13  Tailor Gorwood  5642.66
1.6.5   Winny Burnup    8824.46
1.6.11  Averil Tofpik   9158.9
1.6.10  Arnuad Gwinnel  1459.78
1.2.3   Ethe Village    7081.24
1.2.10  Wadsworth Whiteoak  4985.22
1.6.12  Pippo Oriel 26.89
1.5.13  Glendon Slott   6064.91
1.2.12  Gran Shipperbottom  5430.05
1.1.2   Cobby Sydry 7770.37
1.2.10  Mame Batt   1130.34
1.5.13  Starlin De Bruyne   8254.86
1.6.1   Hussein Wheeliker   455.92
1.2.15  Jessalin Larvor 4779.36
1.2.13  Thorvald Chance 2039.59
1.4.13  Rudolfo Weitzel 9651.71
1.6.11  King Odo    9443.33
1.1.2   Elden Lynnett   8497.92
1.3.14  Ninon Suffe 9187.22
1.5.13  Edvard Porker   7671
1.1.15  Scotty Trench   9640.28
1.6.1   Joana Goom  1543.46
1.5.10  Alaric Pallesen 7937.06
1.5.14  Seth Bakster    435.27
1.4.2   Scotty Trench   2863.49
1.3.2   Cobby Sydry 9951.17
1.3.11  Etti Crum   8722.31
1.4.1   Dietrich Royden 7551.89
1.5.2   Micah Farrier   9061.38
1.1.12  Benjie Caldecot 3396.55
1.2.7   Brandyn Hatchell    9167.39
1.5.12  Sheeree Earney  8820.01
1.4.10  Blake Arthey    7874.45
1.6.8   Mame Batt   4614.38
1.2.9   Conni Bentje    7949.21
1.3.3   Margette Cawthry    9276.79
1.4.15  Kimball Mayzes  7921.72
1.2.3   Wadsworth Whiteoak  2024.73
1.2.12  Ciro Pyser  2121.89
1.2.10  Odetta Morden   7356.49
1.6.6   Pier Lingwood   9515.89
1.2.5   Kimball Mayzes  1662.24
1.5.8   Dorry Giroldo   9694.62
1.4.9   Berry Dilloway  2767.12
1.2.14  Sheeree Earney  6961.9
1.3.14  Kaia Giannazzo  2420.6
1.2.15  Anabel Agg  5753.69
1.4.1   Pier Lingwood   4286.38
1.1.4   Cobby Sydry 9551.02
1.2.5   Kimball Mayzes  9599.14
1.5.5   Anthony Gawke   2982.65
1.6.6   Garvey Kieff    4134.92
1.6.8   Rudolfo Weitzel 6804.66
1.1.10  Winny Burnup    2536.83
1.4.12  Monique Hullyer 3188.34
1.4.8   Benjie Caldecot 1703.77
1.4.7   Guntar Scurlock 3580
1.5.5   Gary Sager  7416.47
1.5.13  Lamond Bromwich 1212.53
1.3.9   Simeon Galfour  4191.34
1.6.14  Hendrick Twort  9178.48
1.6.4   Norry Waghorn   6560.74
1.4.8   Evelyn Duffil   1689.59
1.3.1   Zacharias Lucchi    7910.1
1.5.4   Guntar Scurlock 2516.65
1.5.12  Starlin De Bruyne   8335.79
1.3.6   Blake Arthey    475.06
1.5.9   Anabel Agg  8156.9
1.1.4   North Betho 7443.67
1.5.3   Tris Freshwater 1976.69
1.2.2   Rudolfo Weitzel 2614.52
1.4.14  Brandyn Hatchell    6922.77
1.5.10  Wadsworth Whiteoak  6780.62
1.6.4   Mame Batt   2738.87
1.5.13  Averil Tofpik   5282.5
1.4.5   Fayina Siveter  6537.79
1.5.6   Moll Duddan 3153.9
1.3.5   Blake Arthey    6048.85
1.6.13  Camella Feaster 447.08
1.1.3   Milli Oneal 7716.36
1.2.12  North Betho 859.93
1.5.10  Zoe McGaffey    1750.78
1.3.14  Lamond Bromwich 7722.23
1.4.12  Lamond Bromwich 681.67
1.1.10  Moll Duddan 1334.75
1.3.1   Torry Ouldcott  474.97
1.4.14  Hendrick Twort  5558.32
1.2.9   Emmi Simmonett  1889.29
1.2.6   Averil Tofpik   7872.54
1.6.7   Ninon Suffe 3694.26
1.1.12  Allie Cleaton   3385.1
1.5.13  Camella Feaster 8852.91
1.5.14  Alaric Pallesen 5133.26
1.1.1   Jessalin Larvor 7717.01
1.6.13  Scotty Trench   9588.61
1.4.13  Inglis Glossop  4446.08
1.6.9   Carolina Snook  9178.83
1.1.3   Fayina Siveter  2289.41
1.3.2   Cobby Sydry 4747.45
1.5.1   Correy Fiddyment    4428.32
1.6.3   Laure Barbour   7960.94
1.5.13  Eugine Price    6739.85
1.6.6   Mame Batt   9919.9
1.2.13  Ethe Village    5614.1
1.5.11  Gary Sager  1346.22
1.5.11  Tailor Gorwood  4987.71
1.6.11  Ethe Village    286.39
1.1.13  Kimball Mayzes  3303.14
1.2.14  Allie Cleaton   809.35
1.1.15  Berry Dilloway  2154.18
1.6.5   Glendon Slott   2258.63
1.1.2   Seth Bakster    2521.41
1.2.6   Monique Hullyer 6650.24
1.2.12  Ethe Village    9675.22
1.2.6   Inglis Glossop  9337.48
1.1.4   North Betho 4288.61
1.6.7   Cobby Sydry 5656.37
1.6.2   Starlin De Bruyne   5424.96
1.6.3   Edvard Porker   673.88
1.4.10  Margette Cawthry    8201.7
1.1.9   Mame Batt   6268.96
1.6.9   Odetta Morden   8251.84
1.1.3   Dorry Giroldo   7601.55
1.6.9   Anthony Gawke   1953.13
1.3.5   Seth Bakster    9384.6
1.2.9   Simeon Galfour  8041.35
1.1.6   Ethe Village    1392.31
1.1.10  Micah Farrier   3180.34
1.4.6   Ninon Suffe 1811.5
1.6.9   Eugine Price    7454.75
1.3.14  Adair Anfossi   9246.09
1.2.5   Donnie Stilliard    5551.42
1.2.2   Immanuel Earwicker  3024.58
1.4.14  Carolina Snook  6681.42
1.6.15  Kaia Giannazzo  9439.79
1.4.15  Scotty Trench   3409.05
1.5.5   Milli Oneal 6738.34
1.2.5   Dorry Giroldo   9179.4
1.4.5   Laurens Mordey  5541.85
1.1.4   Clive Astbury   319.52
1.6.2   Monique Hullyer 6062.36
1.6.4   Fay Ambrozewicz 3507.74
1.4.1   Ciro Pyser  4610.95
1.3.13  Marmaduke Flynn 5547.98
1.4.8   Zacharias Lucchi    3077.01
1.6.7   Mame Batt   7611.52
1.6.10  Starlin De Bruyne   6263.68
1.5.15  Dietrich Royden 924.37
1.5.14  Anabel Agg  2594.8
1.5.15  Berry Dilloway  7841.41
1.1.15  Wadsworth Whiteoak  112.63
1.6.9   Anthony Gawke   8409.04
1.6.1   Fayina Stubley  1882.21
1.6.12  Milli Oneal 4495.26
1.5.4   Allie Cleaton   7637.98
1.5.10  Myrah Gwilt 135.67
1.5.9   Karyn Guild 4645.94
1.2.4   Conni Bentje    6265.96
1.4.1   Eugine Price    1704.05
1.3.2   Zacharias Lucchi    1593.4
1.3.4   Wadsworth Whiteoak  3546.95
1.4.6   Adair Anfossi   8097.89
1.4.14  Benjie Caldecot 3145.23
1.1.11  Winny Burnup    8353.55
1.4.14  Adair Anfossi   2285.04
1.3.1   Winny Burnup    4690.38
1.5.11  Ciro Pyser  426.34
1.3.2   Lilllie Blanket 3115.34
1.1.6   Evelyn Duffil   3786.4
1.1.8   Anthony Gawke   1738.06
1.2.12  Arlyne Cooling  1136.71
1.2.8   Tracey Prest    5963.68
1.4.6   Zacharias Lucchi    5576.77
1.5.2   Tailor Gorwood  7976.69
1.4.3   Monique Hullyer 899.77
1.3.3   Clive Astbury   3096.9
1.6.5   Joelly Piller   8317.62
1.2.9   North Betho 6881.52
1.3.1   Wadsworth Whiteoak  8829.86
1.4.3   Simeon Galfour  4027.66
1.3.11  Dorry Giroldo   8292.8
1.1.10  Mame Batt   8338.06
1.1.15  Hussein Wheeliker   5542.09
1.2.9   Inglis Glossop  5357.96
1.4.7   Alaric Pallesen 3522.68
1.6.3   Myrah Gwilt 9487.19
1.5.8   Zoe McGaffey    4927.18
1.2.2   Tailor Gorwood  6762.69
1.3.1   Norry Waghorn   8241.22
1.2.8   Milli Oneal 3521.88
1.1.12  Kimball Mayzes  4010.2
1.5.11  Eugine Price    9132.82
1.2.2   Berry Dilloway  9906.95
1.2.2   King Odo    8924.77
1.2.3   Alfonse Newbery 9099.28
1.1.2   Allie Cleaton   4524.2
1.2.10  Cobby Sydry 2058.26
1.3.11  Fayina Stubley  761.8
1.5.10  Karyn Guild 3569.37
1.3.12  Cynthia Alwin   4959.96
1.2.4   Alfonse Newbery 411.5
```

---

Using `=SUMIFS(Invoice[Amount],Invoice[Task],Tasks[Foo])` without wrapping it in `SUMPRODUCT` returns the following array (not a singular point of data):

`{43347;53040.19;26703.08;38802.35;34684.7;36562.58;21712.18;33018.48;40556.49;51365.17;40373.48;45446.01;58579.04;42628.57;53985.9}`

By adding `SUMPRODUCT` in I get `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Invoice[Amount],Invoice[Task],Tasks[Foo]))` which produces the sum of the array for a value of `620805.22`.

---

However this is not that value I seek, instead I need to fill the following empty table:

```
Employee Group      Planning    Implementation  Steady State    ODC Foo Bar
Employees                       
Project Managers                        
Business Analysts                       
Boss People
```

Converting my above original formula, I end up with `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Invoice[Amount],Invoice[Task],Tasks[Planning],Invoice[Name],Employee[Employees]))` to generate the top-right data point, adjusting the checked columns to fill in the other portions produces this table:

```
Employee Group      Planning    Implementation  Steady State    ODC     Foo     Bar
Employees           4906.4      9099.28         7304.19         9592.36 7637.98 7052.42
Project Managers    0           4787.27         7817.06         4828.01 0       9218.27
Business Analysts   11732.28    0               4699.27         0       0       0
Boss People         0           3688.42         0               6537.79 0       1543.46
```

However this is incorrect, the correct output (and my desired one) for this table would be as follows:

```
Employee Group      Planning    Implementation  Steady State    ODC         Foo         Bar
Employees           350768.13   414497.03       371251.29       351048.08   425505.16   421203.44
Project Managers    134495.8    149973.37       96308.11        156993.39   110168.09   157218.6
Business Analysts   83205.62    86716.72        100948.37       64753.08    52688.76    54117.86
Boss People         31909.67    23487.14        14910.01        21902.5     32443.21    50055.96
```

To reiterate:

#### What is wrong with my current formula, and what should be changed in order to find the correct results?

Comment: My understanding of how nested formula works is not what you describe. Sumproduct works when you have more than one array. Currently, the only array you are giving it is the **result** of sumifs. So if you extract sumifs from sumproduct, you will get the result that sumproduct will work with, and in that case it should be the same result as there are no other arrays to do the sumproduct with.

Comment: @Pomul, Thanks for the comment. When you only have 1 array in SumProduct, it will simply sum up the values of that array, for instance if I had the values `1, 1; 2, 2; 3, 3` in rows 1-3 columns A-B and did SUMPRODUCT(A1:B3), it'd provide a result of 12.

Comment: In this case, since I'm using SUMIFS to compare ranges, it returns an array of results, that would not be summed together. I simply use SUMPRODUCT to sum those values together, getting the total sum of values in the array. As mentioned above, using a singular set of criteria provides the correct results, it's only when I use ranges for both sets of criteria that I run into issues.

Comment: SUMIFS does not return an array of results, it returns the sum of a range when all conditions are met. You can check by using SUMIFS alone in a cell. Using a singular criteria works because sumporduct does not have an array to work with, only the result of sumifs with one criteria. If SUMIFS with one criteria returns 10, then sumproduct(10) = 10, hence the "correct" result. But if SUMIFS with mutliple criteria returns 5, then sumproduct(5) = 5, which is also a correct result, but not the one you are looking for.

Comment: If you can provide data with your quesiton, along with the expected output, it would be most helpful.

Comment: @Pomul, I have added in data, and explained why `SUMIFS` alone does not suffice for me in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you have duplicate names in your employee list. For those duplicate, since there is no way to tell in what category the amount should be counted, it will be counted in all categories that the employee is listed under.

(Kristoffer is both a Boss and Employee, so his amounts will be added to both Boss and Employee categories). I doubt you are ok with this because the following formula gives you the output you have provided for Boss People/Foo, but not for Employees/Foo:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Boss_People[Name],Invoice[Full Name])*(COUNTIF(Task[Foo],Invoice[Task]))*Invoice[Amount])
```

If you want the names to change dynamically so that you can copy/drag your formula across - and assuming your summary table starts in A1, this is the formula for B2:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT($A2&"[Name]"),Invoice[[Full Name]:[Full Name]])*(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Task["&B$1&"]"),Invoice[[Task]:[Task]]))*Invoice[[Amount]:[Amount]])
```

Here, cell A2 contains the name of the table which has a column header titled "Name" and B1 the name of the task. This formula gives you the output wanted for Project Managers, Business Analysts and Boss People. Employees is not accurate because of duplicate names.

Comment: You are correct in that I didn't realize the example data had some duplicate values in the columns. This is precisely what I needed.